# SVG Кривая c изменяемым размером длинны

Tags: css, css3, svg, design

Есть необходимость построить блок в дизайне которого, встречается изогнутая градиентная кривая, как на рисунке. Как это сделать, если неизвестно сколько текста будет в СЕО блоке, и необходимо чтобы данная кривая имела возможность "тянуться" по высоте в зависимости от родителя с текстом

[image: кривая SVG]

Пример кода я накидал

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #17161d;
}

.bl_fullWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 220px;
}

.bl_left,
.bl_right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}

.bl_left {
  width: calc(80% - 300px);
  margin-right: 5%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bl_right {
  width: 25%;
}

.bl_img {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #1e1b27;
}

.bl_img img {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: -26px;
}

.curvedLine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_fullWrapper">
  <div class="bl_left">
    <h1 class="main_title">Title text very long</h1>
    <p class="text_ceo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, similique et eius ratione suscipit corporis iste impedit libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum.libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bl_right">
    <div class="bl_img">
      <img class="main_images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x220/0000FF/808080 ?Text=Digital.com" alt="main images">
    </div>
  </div>

  <svg class="curvedLine" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 600 220" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 220;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="149" y1="120.5" x2="590.3333" y2="120.5">
 <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#EF8E34"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#CA375F"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st0" d="M149,213v7h237.3c9.9,0,18-8.1,18-18V47c0-9.9,8.1-18,18-18h168v-8H415c-9.9,0-18,8.1-18,18v157.2
 c0,10-8.1,18.1-18.1,18L149,213z"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

только он не адаптивный, как хотелось бы. Кто может посоветовать, как  реализовать данный элемент дизайна, желательно без JS, средствами CSS + SVG ?

Comment: Я бы сприптом path нарисовал, но в принципе наверное можно за счёт scale в разных пропорциях, с отключённом масштабированием толщины stroke

Comment: @BlackStar1991 если бы у Вас были хоть сколько нибудь корректные стили и разметка, то можно было бы обойтись всего двумя псевдоэлементами, без JS и SVG.

Comment: @UModeL это через :before, :after что ли, присвоеное к бокам? А скругление как обеспечить, а плавность перехода градиента в зависимости от длинны сео блока.... ? или вы тут себя самым умным считаете

Comment: @BlackStar1991 почему к бокам? Есть ещё верх и низ. Скругление - `border-radius` же, не? Плавность обеспечит `linear-gradient`. И причём здесь зависимость от длины *блока*? От длины текста, наверное, которая влияет на *высоту* блока, так? Может быть я самый умный, но это не моя вина ;-)

Comment: @UModeL ты ему утёр нос ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильнее было бы сверстать на `flex` без `inline-block`, но что есть, то есть...

Надеюсь, что выставите нужные отступы, в соответствии с макетом:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

body { background-color: #17161d; }

.bl_fullWrapper {
  min-height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.bl_left,
.bl_right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
}

.bl_left {
  width: calc(100% - 365px);
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.bl_left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -4px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ca375f;
  border-right: 3px solid #ca375f;
}

div.bl_left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  right: -4px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  width: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ca375f, #ef8e34);
}

.bl_right { width: 360px; }

div.bl_right:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #ef8e34;
  border-left: 3px solid #ef8e34;
}

.bl_img {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #1e1b27;
  box-shadow: 16px -16px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bl_img img { border-radius: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="bl_fullWrapper">
  <div class="bl_left">
    <h1 class="main_title">Title text very long</h1>
    <p class="text_ceo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, similique et eius ratione suscipit corporis iste impedit libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum.libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum libero, fuga natus, dignissimos autem harum temporibus neque tenetur facere fugiat iusto. Vero accusantium impedit placeat ea,
      consectetur nesciunt repellat minima dicta soluta qui, pariatur fugiat exercitationem, optio quae iure sint labore rerum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bl_right">
    <div class="bl_img">
      <img class="main_images" src="//via.placeholder.com/300x220/0000FF/808080?Text=Digital.com" alt="main images">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Разверните на всю страницу и изменяйте размер окна браузера, чтобы проверить адаптивность.*